# ORACLE SQL Query records where date falls between minimum and maximum date from other table

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, date-range

In TABLE_A there is for each ID a minimum SDT and maximum EDT.

> Example: for ID=1000 this will be 1/09/2013 and 3/10/2013.
>
> Example: for ID=1001 this will be 1/07/2013  and 3/08/2013.

The expected result will be all records from TABLE_B where the SDT from TABLE_B falls between those minimum SDT and maximum EDT values from TABLE_A.

[Example Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a196f4)

**TABLE_A**

```
ID      SDT          EDT
------------------------------
1000    1/10/2013    3/10/2013  
1000    1/09/2013    3/09/2013   
1001    1/08/2013    3/08/2013
1001    1/07/2013    3/07/2013
1002    1/06/2013    3/06/2013
```

**TABLE_B**

```
ID      SDT
-----------------
1000    2/10/2013   ===> because it falls between 1/09/2013 and 3/10/2013
1000    4/09/2013   ===> because it falls between 1/09/2013 and 3/10/2013
1001    2/08/2013   ===> because it falls between 1/07/2013  and 3/08/2013
1001    4/05/2013   ==> not in result because it's not between 1/07/2013 and 3/08/2013
1002    4/06/2013   ==> also out of range, so not in results
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by for the min/max values and a correlated sub query to relate to `table_b`

```
Select
    *
From
    Table_b b
Where
    Exists (
        Select
            'x'
        From
            table_a a
        Where
            a.id = b.id
        group by
            a.id
        having
            min(a.sdt) <= b.sdt and
            max(a.edt) >= b.sdt
  )
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a196f4/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that using a GROUP BY in the subquery will have unnecessary performance costs.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM table_b b
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_a a
    WHERE b.sdt BETWEEN LEAST(a.sdt, e.edt) AND GREATEST(a.edt, a.sdt)
      AND a.id = b.id
);
```

Edit/Correction:
This solution would only apply if you were matching against the individual rows in table_a, not a MIN/MAX grouping. I had previously overlooked the MIN/MAX grouping requirement from table_a.

The following uses two EXISTS queries without a GROUP BY and returns the correct results:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM table_b b
WHERE (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_a a
    WHERE b.sdt >= a.sdt 
    AND a.id = b.id
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_a a
    WHERE b.sdt <= a.edt 
    AND a.id = b.id
));
```

Comment: Ah, I had missed the grouping requirement when I first read this. You are correct sir. :)

If it were looking for BETWEEN matches against the individual rows, then my query would have correct.